# The "Named Constructor Idiom" seems to contradict the rule that a static method cannot access a non-static member function. Any explanation?

Tags: c++, constructor, static-methods

According to this [site](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.8) the static methods

```
static Point rectangular(float x, float y);    
static Point polar(float radius, float angle);
```

invoke the private constructor `Point` (a non-static method) as reproduced below :

```
#include <cmath>               // To get std::sin() and std::cos()

class Point {
 public:
   static Point rectangular(float x, float y);      // Rectangular coord's
   static Point polar(float radius, float angle);   // Polar coordinates
   // These static methods are the so-called "named constructors"
   ...
 private:
   Point(float x, float y);     // Rectangular coordinates
   float x_, y_;
 };

 inline Point::Point(float x, float y)
   : x_(x), y_(y) { }

 inline Point Point::rectangular(float x, float y)
 { return Point(x, y); }

 inline Point Point::polar(float radius, float angle)
 { return Point(radius*std::cos(angle), radius*std::sin(angle)); }
};
```

**Edit: I'm having difficulties accepting an answer, since I don't know which one is correct.**

Comment: A constructor is more akin to a static member function than a non-static one.

Comment: A static member function *can* call a non-static one, if it has an object to call it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor is a special case, because **a constructor doesn't need an existing object** to be called.

The rule you mention would be better remembered as *"A static member function doesn't have an implicit `this` pointer"*.

Comment: Correct, @user1042389.  It doesn't require one to be called, though.  That's the key.

Comment: Although I don't agree with your statement "It doesn't require one to be called", I'm inclined to think you got the right answer as **a constructor doesn't need an existing object to be called**, so a constructor can be "called" from a static function. But as far as I can understand, the `this` pointer for the ctor exists in the example, and is the address of the temporary created on the stack, inside the static functions.

Comment: @user1042389: I think we're on the same page.  Creating a `Point` implies either allocating heap memory or reserving stack memory, and then the constructor is called with `this` pointing to that memory.  At some point during this process, there will be a valid `this` pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot *call* a constructor, and neither does the `rectangular` function. All it does is *construct* a new object and return a copy of it.

Constructors are special member functions that have no name and cannot be called by the user. They can only be called implicitly as part of the language, namely either through initialization of a static or automatic object, or through a `new` expression. You cannot take the address of a constructor, and a constructor cannot be `const`- or otherwise qualified.

If you think about it that way, then nobody is calling any non-static member functions of any object, and there *is* no problem. Note also that the very notion of "member function" wouldn't make sense for a constructor, since member functions are called on *objects*, but there isn't any object until some constructor has already *completed*.

In short, constructors are a special part of the language itself, and cannot be treated just as the special case of some other concept.

Comment: "there isn't any object until some constructor has already completed" - well, the terminology in the standard is arguably a bit confusing on this point. It refers to "objects under construction", so I think there is an object, but its "lifetime" hasn't yet started. Quite possibly this doesn't make sense, but even if not the standard says it anyway so it's true. Most relevant to what you said, it *is* possible to call member functions on objects under construction, but of course not (directly) from the code containing the initialization, which has no reference to the object under construction.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the "rule" you cite (which it really isn't) is that a `static` member function doesn't have a implicit instance it operates on, i.e. no `this`.

However, a `static` member function *can* invoke a non-`static` member function if it has an instance that it can invoke the member function on. In this case, it creates its own instance by invoking the private constructor.

Compare (trivial example, I admit)

```
class Greeter {
    std::string who;

  public:
    Greeter(std::string const &name) : who(name) { }

    static void greet(Greeter const &gr) { gr.hello(); }

  private:
    void hello() { std::cout << "Hello, " << who << "!\n"; }
 };
```

Here, the `static` member `greet` is used to invoke the `private` method `hello`. It can do so because it gets passed an explicit `Greeter` instance. (This would not work with a freestanding function, unless it was declared a `friend`.)

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is somewhat between static and non-static: a constructor can not be called on an instance of an object, but inside the constructor you have access to the object just created. However, a constructor is always called statically (i.e. on the type and not on an instance), so this is not really an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

rectangular() and polar() are returning unnamed Point objects by calling the constructor directly. The reason you can't normally call instance methods from a static method is because no instance exists yet. When a constructors is invoked directly, it creates an unnamed instance prior to executing the constructor body.

Answer (score 0):

> The “Named Constructor Idiom” seems to contradict the rule that a
>   static method cannot access a non-static member function. Any
>   explanation?

The reason behind the rule you quote "that a static member function cannot access a non-static member function" is because a static member function doesn't have a this pointer. And need a this function to all a normal non-static member function.

But constructor is a special member function that has many special rules applied to use:

e.g from c++ standard 3290
12.1 A constructor shall not be virtual (10.3) or static (9.4).

And you must know already that you can invoke a constructor without a instance of this class, without a this pointer. 
That's why you can instantiate a class inside a static member function or whatever you like in the global scope just like(as long as it has the definition):

```
Point(x, y);
```

So does this explain your question ?